# What do 1 and -1 stand for in mongoose compound indexes?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

You can see it in the example in their official docs: [guide#indexes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

Why is name set to `1` and type set to `-1`?

Comment: they set the sort order of the fields in the index. 1 is ascending, -1 would be descending

Comment: yeah. it wasn't obvious in mongoose docs. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the mongodb docs

> Sort Order
>
> Indexes store references to fields in either ascending (1) or descending (-1) sort order.

See here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/

So, as per your example, `name` is ascending, `type` is desecending